# testSetup in Managed Package running in Target Org on Installation

Tags: managed-package

I am in the process of releasing a new version of a managed package, and in doing so, decided to take advantage of the new @testsetup annotation, and that all seems to work fine.

However, when I tried to install this package in target orgs, I started hitting org-specific errors regarding problems with validation rules on Accounts, Contacts and Leads (the test scripts create some Accounts, Contact and Lead record)

As various posts here on StackEx have detailed, tests for a managed package should not run in a target org unless explicitly set to, and I am installing these packages via the UI. So I used subscriber access to login from my LMA, and install it logged in as the Publisher. Looking in the Dev Console Logs, I see a a job called 'waitingJobPage' that appears to run all the testsetup methods from each class that uses them (three in all) and when I add a validation rule for Account in my target org, it does indeed fail to run.

Any ideas what is happening here? Haven't seen anything in docs to say this expected behavior, nor any guidance on how to avoid it?

Comment: Just raised a case and saw in the partner portal that other users are having the same issue, so this looks like a (nasty) bug